# Why NGINX can't find a shared library called from Lua block?

Tags: c, nginx, lua

So I want to load library written in C from `content_by_lua_block`.

Here is my `nginx.conf`:

```
http {
         server {
            listen 8080;
            location / {
                    default_type text/html;
                    
                    content_by_lua_block {
                        local ffi = require("ffi")
                        local lib = ffi.load("ffi_example5")
                        
                        // do smth here...
                    }
            
             }
          }
}
```

`ffi_example5.c`:

```
int get_value() {
     return 5;
}
```

How I compile and run it all. `run_server.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -ueo pipefail

mkdir -p logs

export PATH=/usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin:$PATH

gcc -fPIC -c -o scripts/ffi_example5.o scripts/ffi_example5.c
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,/usr/local/lib/libffi_example5.so -o /usr/local/lib/libffi_example5.so scripts/ffi_example5.o

nginx -s reload -c conf/nginx.conf
```

Project structure:

```
./run_server.sh
conf/:
    nginx.conf
scripts/:
    ffi_example5.c
```

And my error from logs:

```
2023/07/29 18:49:37 [error] 97686#0: *361 lua entry thread aborted: runtime error: content_by_lua(nginx.conf:16):3: libffi_example5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
stack traceback:
coroutine 0:
    [C]: in function 'load'
    content_by_lua(nginx.conf:16):3: in main chunk, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080"
```

What I have already tried:

1. Setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` : `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib:.`
2. Adding `include /usr/local/lib` to `/etc/ld.so.conf`
3. Run `ldconfig`
4. Leaving `lib[libraryname].so` in a `conf/` directory (where `nginx.conf` is located) as well as placing it in `/usr/local/lib`

Didn't help